# How to parse NSDictionary of unnamed arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

Here is the `NSLog` result of a dictionary, `dict`:

```
  (
     {
         namelists = {
                        watchlist = (a, b, c, ... )
                     }
     },

     {
         namelists = {
                        watchlist = (x, y, z, ... )
                     }
     }
   )
```

How can I get the watchlist array?  When I tried this:

```
  NSAarray *array = dict[@"nameLists"][@"watchlist"]
```

I get error: "unrecognized selector sent to instance".  I think that the unnamed array is not referred here.  How can I get the watchlist array?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'Here is the dictionary dict looks like' - That is not a dictionary. It is an array of dictionaries. You are getting unrecognized select because you are treating an array as a dictionary.

Comment: BTW, if you don't mind my pointing this out, while we were able to make educated guess what the error was, in the future, please share the full error message with us. Specifically, the error probably said something like "`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8aa0d00'`". That stuff before "unrecognized selector" is really important because it tells us that `objectForKeyedSubscript` method (which is what the dictionary subscripting syntax calls) was used with an array.

Comment: If you bother to read the "unrecognized selector" message you'll see that it's plainly telling you that you have an array, not a dictionary.  The array contains two dictionaries.  (Hint:  See the `()` characters?  That's how an NSArray dumps under NSLog.)

Answer (score 3):

You're under the impression that you're dealing with a dictionary. But that's an array of dictionaries. So you want:

```
NSArray *jsonObject = ... // get that main object however you want, presumably NSJSONSerialization
NSArray *watchlist = jsonObject[0][@"namelists"][@"watchlist"]
```

or

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in jsonObject)
{
    NSArray *watchlist = dict[@"namelists"][@"watchlist"];

    // now do something with watchlist
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob.  It is typo.  I did the same way.  Just want to see is there a better way without using the index [0].

Comment: @user2543991 Well, that `jsonObject` is an array, so you have to deal with it as such. lol. You either have to use the index, or you could enumerate through the array, e.g. `for (NSDictionary *dict in jsonObject) { ... }`, where at that point, you can use `dict` inside that `for` loop like you did in your original question.

Comment: @user2543991: *"I did the same way"* - then why did you get an  "unrecognized selector sent to instance" exception? - *"It is typo"* - Please always copy/paste your actual code. Everything else means wasting your and our time.

Comment: @Rob: You gave the correct answer to the original question. - What OP *might* be looking for is `valueForKeyPath:` to extract an array of all "watchlist" entries in one step.

Comment: @MartinR Perhaps. Unless he clarifies what he means by "better way without using index", we're just guessing. A little more context to the question would be helpful. Regardless, hopefully we've given him enough at this point for him to figure out the rest on his own.

Comment: Thanks Rob and Martin.  Sorry not state it clearly.  What I want is an easy way, like array = [@""][@"namelists"][@"watchlist"] to get the watchlist array.

Comment: @user2543991 There's a disconnect between your data structure (an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects) and how you want to access it (as an `NSDictionary` with `NSDictionary` objects), so that question doesn't really make sense. You have to either change how you're accessing the data (e.g. `NSArray *watchlist = jsonObject[0][@"namelists"][@"watchlist"];`) or change how you're storing it. But you shouldn't try to use a `NSDictionary` subscript (e.g. `[@"..."]`) with an `NSArray`.

Answer (score 1):

this data structure can be coded like this

```
NSArray *arrayOfNamelists = @[@{@"namelists" : @{@"watchlist" : @[@"a",@"b",@"c"]}},
                              @{@"namelists" : @{@"watchlist" : @[@"x",@"y",@"z"]}}];
```

and an element in the array of strings can be accessed like this

```
NSString *entry = [[arrayOfNamelists[1] objectForKey:@"namelists"]
                   objectForKey:@"watchlist"][2];
```

which in this example gives 'z'

To check this

```
NSLog(@"%@\ncount = %i",arrayOfNamelists,arrayOfNamelists.count);

for(NSDictionary *namelistDictionary in arrayOfNamelists){
    NSDictionary *watchlistDictionary = [namelistDictionary objectForKey:@"namelists"];
    NSArray *watchlistsArray = [watchlistDictionary objectForKey:@"watchlist"];
    for(NSString *watchlistEntry in watchlistsArray){
        NSLog(@"%@",watchlistEntry);
    }
};
```

gives

```
(
    {
    namelists =         {
        watchlist =             (
            a,
            b,
            c
        );
    };
},
    {
    namelists =         {
        watchlist =             (
            x,
            y,
            z
        );
    };
}
```

)

count = 2

a

b

c

x

y

z